# XMLRPC and Drupal

Tags: c#, drupal, drupal-6, xml-rpc

I'm using XMLRPC to create a user and am getting the following two errors:

```
Illegal choice C in Roles element.
Illegal choice C in Status element
```

As show by the Recent Log Entries report.

I'm using C# and the XMLRPC (Cook computing) assembly to make my call. I am able to successfully connect and login to the server. The SessionID and cookies are working. I just think there is something I'm missing in user create.

Here are the parameters I'm sending:

```
[XmlRpcMethod("user.create")]
Drupal UserCreate(string name, string mail, string pass, string status);
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error?
Notes: I'm running Drupal 6.22 with Services 3.0.

Comment: You've asked to edit your code into Clive's answer. If that doesn't get approved you could alternatively edit it into the bottom of your question.

Comment: I think that's also not really the appropriate place for a solution; the most SO-like thing to do here is probably to add your specific solution code as another answer (or describe it in a comment on Clive's answer). Although it seems weird, it's totally OK to answer your own question on SO.

Comment: If he likes the edits he can accept them, if not, the answer is perfectly fine as it is.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `/sites/all/modules/services/resources/user_resource.inc`, at the `_user_resource_create()` function you'll see the user is added by simulating the submission of the [`user_register` form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_register/6). This form requires a `roles` array parameter with at least one user role in it which you're not currently passing.

I'm not 100% about the `status` error but try changing the `c#` type to an `int` as that's what it is in the Drupal database.